# Group data by quintiles in Amazon Redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a dataset which has customer information regarding the number of orders they have placed, their order value and their customer id.
I am trying to find out what is the average order value of the customers, how many orders they have placed and what is the total revenue they generated in the month of November. However, I also want to group this into quintiles to see what were these values for the top 5%, next 5% and so on. I want to group them into quintiles based on the customers total order values.

So far I have tried:

```
select customer_number , orders, amount,
percentile_cont(0.95) within group(order by amount) over(partition by customer_account_id) as ninetyfive,
percentile_cont(0.90) within group(order by amount) over(partition by customer_account_id) as ninety,
from(
select customer_number , count(ordernum) as orders, sum(amount_paid) as amount
from data_table
and date_part(month ,order_date) = 11
and date_part(year, order_date) =2021
group by customer_number
order by amount desc
)
group by customer_number, orders, amount
order by amount desc;
```

Comment: I have not access to redshift DB, but just fixed your query for PostgreSQL. You can look https://sqlize.online/sql/psql14/a5db0ab61e273740f7d194a0df9e8148/

Comment: What I want to know is, how many customers exist in the 95th percentile and the average ordernum and amount_paid for this group? Rather than 1 row for each of their customer_number with their individual ordernum and amount_paid  values.